# How to send my location as reply when I receive a message through Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, location, broadcastreceiver, sms, locationlistener

I need to send my current Latitude and Longitude as reply to a message received through broadcast receiver.
So far i have completed the broadcast receiver and a plain text reply.Now I need to add my location to it.

Please help me with this.

This is my **BroadcastReceiver** class

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


private static final String TAG = "SmsBroadcastReceiver";

private Listener listener;

public SmsBroadcastReceiver() {

}


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
        String smsSender = "";
        String smsBody = "";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                smsSender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                smsBody += smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            }
        } else {
            Bundle smsBundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (smsBundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) smsBundle.get("pdus");
                if (pdus == null) {
                    // Display some error to the user
                    Log.e(TAG, "SmsBundle had no pdus key");
                    return;
                }
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    smsBody += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                }
                smsSender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            }
        }


        if (smsBody.startsWith("Lost")) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onTextReceived(smsBody);
                Log.e(TAG, "SMS RECEIVED");
            }




            Toast.makeText(context, smsBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(smsSender, null, "Your Phone is at latitude,longitude ", null, null);

        }


    }

}

void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

interface Listener {
    void onTextReceived(String text);
}

 }
```

I have tried implementing LocationListener as an inner class but I got null value for the latitude and longitude

Comment: Very good that you nowhere mentioned sms!

Comment: _I need to send my current Latitude and Longitude as **reply to a message** received through broadcast receiver._ I guess this means sms @greenapps

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you don not have Permission .

get these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

and for api>21

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.BROADCAST_SMS,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
            1);
```

Comment: Firstly, how do you know that he needs permissions? You could have first asked him in the comments section. Secondly, runtime permission is not required in api 22 and 23, so it should've been api>23.

Comment: I have all these permissions @Radesh